# How to add x-xss-protection header in django?

Tags: django, http, header

I can't seem to add x-xss-protection header to a HttpResponse object.

Basically, I want to be able to override the x-xss-protection: "1; mode=block;" header, since it's giving me this error message on Webkit browsers (Safari and Chrome):

> The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in 'http://...' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header

When I tried to add the X-XSS-Protection http header in a HttpResponse object, I get this:

> got an unexpected keyword argument 'x-xss-protection'

It seems that it doesn't support x-xss-protection?! I probably am doing it the wrong way.

I'm not sure if I am supposed to add this at the application level (django) or at the web server level (Apache/nginX).

In my case, it would be preferably doing directly on the view, since I don't want this vulnerability "uncaught" on other django views.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

django-secure can do that for you. You can install it via pip.

To enable the XSS filter in the browser, and force it to always block suspected XSS attacks, you can pass the X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block header. SecurityMiddleware will do this for all responses if the `SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER` setting is `True`.

http://django-secure.readthedocs.org/en/latest/middleware.html

Comment: Since, Django 1.4, you know have a clickjacking module that offers pratically the same methods/middleware. The thing is that I want to remove the X-XSS-Protection. Not added it. It's being already added by default

Comment: My mistake so sorry.  Did you enabled any CSP rules ? Could you post http response header somewhere and paste link over here ? Because I suggest to you solved main issue, not disabling XSS protection. It's really works if you want to secure your clients against XSS.

Comment: Features of django-secure were merged into Django 1.8. If you're using 1.8+ then don't use django-secure, and rather refer to the "Security" Django docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware

Answer (score 8):

@mehmet is right for adding some information :

```
## X-XSS-Protection
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
```

you can also add more secure headers :
more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/security/

```
## X-Frame-Options
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'DENY'
#X-Content-Type-Options
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
## Strict-Transport-Security
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 15768000
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_HSTS_PRELOAD = True

## that requests over HTTP are redirected to HTTPS. aslo can config in webserver
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True 

# for more security
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'
```

Comment: The SecurityMiddleware no longer sets the X-XSS-Protection header if the SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER setting is True. The setting is removed.